# No Method Error, undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys I got an error when I trying to save the data. I already declared a instances variable for the Permits but I still got this error. I have no idea why, anyone can help me with this?

The error is from the `<%= @permits.created_at %>`

```
<%= form_for(@vinvoice) do |f| %>
        <h2>Time : <%= @permits.created_at %></h2></br>
        <h2>Invoice ID : <%= @permits.id %></h2></br>

        <%= f.label :"Vehicle" %>
```

This is my `new.html.erb`

```
<% provide(:title, 'Invoice') %>
<h1>Invoice</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="datashow">

    <%= form_for(@vinvoice) do |f| %>
        <h2>Time : <%= @permits.created_at %></h2></br>
        <h2>Invoice ID : <%= @permits.id %></h2></br>


    <%= f.submit "Make Payment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my `vinvoices_controller.rb`

```
class VinvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @permits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:visitor_permit_id])
    @vinvoice = Vinvoice.new
  end

  def create
    @vinvoice = Vinvoice.new(vinvoice_params)
    if @vinvoice.save
      flash[:success] = "Visitor Permit created!"
      render 'new'
    else
      flash[:error] = @vinvoice.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render 'new'

    end
  end

  private

  def set_vinvoice
    @vinvoice = Vinvoice.find(params[:id])
  end

  def vinvoice_params
    params.require(:vinvoice).permit(:vehicletype, :name, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend, :price, :time, :visitor_permit_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: have you confirm that `@permits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:visitor_permit_id])` finds a record?

Comment: Yep it found the particular records and render it out. But when I want to re save the data again the error came

Answer (score 1):

Effectively you are getting this error message because

```
@permits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:visitor_permit_id])
```

is setting `@permits` to `nil`. Whatever `params[:visitor_permit_id]` is there is no corrisponding `VisitorPermit` recorder in the database with that `id`. I would suggest you use something like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to confirm the value of `params[:visitor_permit_id]`. One common cause for this is that the key in the `params` hash has a typo or is nested so you have to do something like `params[:permit][:visitor_permit_id]` (just an example.

**See SteveTurczyn comment about find vs find_by**

not updating due to educational value of my oversight

Comment: In addition to that, it's probably because you are visiting the new page without a `params[:visitor_permit_id]`. Most likely `localhost:3000/users/new` instead of something like `localhost:3000/users/new?visitor_permit_id=12345`

Comment: `find` won't set `@permits` to nil, it will raise an exception if it's not found.  If the OP had used `find_by` then you might be correct.

Comment: So are you saying that something overwrite the "@permits to nil"? because I'm able to render out the @permits records from the db to the field. I got the error after I pressed the submit button

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are defining `@permits` in your `new` method, but you are NOT defining it in your `create` method.

So when the `create` method detects a problem and renders your `new` form, you have nil value in the `@permits` instance variable.

That's the cause of your problem.

Does the `Vinvoice` object belong to the `VisitorPermit` object?

If so you want to do...

```
def new
  @permits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:visitor_permit_id])
  @vinvoice = Vinvoice.new
  @vinvoice.permit = @permits
end
```

Include the permit id in the form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :permit_id
<%= f.submit "Make Payment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

And in the create, do...

```
def create
  @vinvoice = Vinvoice.new(vinvoice_params)
  @permits = @vinvoice.permit
```

I think in general you want to use `@permit` not `@permits`, though... you seem to be working with a single permit.

Comment: Typo `@invoice.permit` to `@vinvoice`

Comment: Hey if they did a redirect vs the render would he had still run into this issue?

Comment: The trouble with redirect is that it would simply create a "new" `new` form... he would not see any of the values he had input on the first form, and the "new" `@vinvoice` object would not have any errors so he couldn't output `@vinvoice.errors.full_messages` to show what was wrong with the input.  `render` is correct, but ideally you should have only one instance variable in the view.

Comment: Number 4 in Sandi Metz' rules for devleoipers:  Controllers can instantiate only one object. Therefore, views can only know about one instance variable and views should only send messages to that object (@object.collaborator.value is not allowed).   https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers

Comment: Yea I know that Sandi Metz rule about one instance variable in a view, it can be hard to achieve that level of organization though especially on you first iteration of an application.

Comment: Okay, I have followed your solution by defining permits in my CREATE action (changed to vinvoice.visitor_permit instead of @permits = @vinvoice.permit). I used vinvoice.errors.full_messages.to_sentence to display any error if the data is not saved and i got an error "Visitor permit must exist"

Comment: Ah is that part of your payment validation?  Maybe you should post you r models.